# Yii2. The model return an Expression object in the field, instead of a string

Tags: php, database, activerecord, yii2

The string is stored in the database as expected. And the object is returned. We are talking about the hash field and hash_actual
If you make a second request and do not fall into the condition, then a string will be returned.
How to be?

```
if ($hashDbCurrent !== $hashDbActual || $currentDateTimeStamp >= $updateDateHashTimeStamp) {
        $cdbExpression = new Expression('MD5(NOW())');
                $mba_info->hash = $cdbExpression;
                $mba_info->hash_actual = $cdbExpression;
                $mba_info->last_date_hash_update = $currentDate;
                $mba_info->save();
            }

  return $mba_info;
```

Before Save we Have String
[image]

After save we Have object. But we have string in Database. I need string after save
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `ActiveRecord::refresh()` - Repopulates this active record with the latest data.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#refresh()-detail